# Compiling an F# 2.0 project in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, visual-studio-2012, fparsec

I have a solution for VS2010 that includes some F# projects that work against the F# 2.0 compiler/SDK, leveraging fparsec and fsharp powerpack.

I then upgraded my main development machine to VS2012, loaded the solution and was able to compile just fine.

However I just repaved a seperate machine with windows 8 and VS2012, and loading the solution on that machine causes compilation failure, as the project is targeting F# 3.0, and fparsec/fsharp powerpack don't appear to compile any more.

Is it possible to install the FSharp 2.0 SDK (and if so, where do I get it from?) on this new windows 8 machine and get the solution to compile again, or would I need to do something else to get this working on both the old and new machine?

**Updated 2012-10-25**

Compilation is now working after restarting VS2012, but when executing code I'm getting an unexpected error related to my F# code:

```
Method not found: 'ParserResult`2<!!0,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit> FParsec.CharParsers.run(
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<FParsec.CharStream`1<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>,
FParsec.Reply`1<!!0>>, System.String)'.
```

This does not happen when compiling/executing the same code on a machine that had first VS2010 installed with F# and then was upgraded to vs2012 - only happening on the machine which has just vs2012 installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like my new issue as the same as the one documented here:

https://bitbucket.org/riles01/fparsec/issue/1/nuget-package-not-working-with-vs2012  going to try the binding redirects and will confirm if that resolves the issue.  Guess environment upgraded from VS2010 already has the F# 2.0 core library installed in the GAC?

Comment: Note that the NuGet package currently doesn't contain the latest version of FParsec. If you have issues with the NuGet package, please try the latest version of FParsec from https://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main/overview, and if you then still have problems, please file a ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the target framework to "4.0" (or lesser), it should compile the same as F# 2.0 (with a few new nice features, such as auto properties). I see no reason to insist on leaving out the new features, and definitely no reason to leave out all the bug fixes that came with F# 3.0 .

Comment: I found the initial compilation error went away after restarting the machine, it was already target .Net Framework 4.0.   However I now have a new problem - will update the question.

Comment: @Bittercoder It seems that Ryan Riley has solved your new issue.